# Using a function parameter inside :not()

Tags: javascript, html

My overall goal is to select all elements in my document EXCLUDING elements in a specified class. Here's my code so far:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(":not(.myParameter)");
```

I want myParameter to be passed into a function so that I could select every element NOT in a ".cars" class for instance or whatever the user defines as myParameter.  I think I'm very close, but might have my quotes wrong.  Any ideas?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(":not(" + myParameter + ")");
```

Comment: Just tried it out and it seems to not be able to match with any elements.  Would the "." need to be prepended to myParameter as well?

Comment: if myParameter is a class name then yes